# Finding the work from $(0,0)\to(1,1)$ of $\vec F(x,y)=xy^2\hat i+yx^2\hat j$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, physics

> I need to find the work from $(0,0)\to(1,0)\to(1,1)$ of the following vector field:$\vec F(x,y)=xy^2\hat i+yx^2\hat j$

**My attempt:**

$$\oint_{c}\vec F  d\vec r=\int_{(0,0)\to (1,0)}\bigg(xy^2\; dx +yx^2 \; dy\bigg)+\int_{(1,1)\nwarrow(1,0)}\bigg(xy^2\; dx+yx^2\; dy\bigg)$$

> Is it correct so far? if yes so how can I proceed from this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**

We can simplify the problem by noting that $\nabla \times \vec F=0$.  Therefore, $\vec F$ is therefore conservative on any connected domain.  By Stokes' Theorem, the integral of $\vec F$ over any contour $C$ that bounds a connected domain $S$ is

$$\oint_C \vec F\cdot d\vec \ell =\int_S \nabla \times \vec F\cdot \hat ndS$$

Thus, the integral of interest is equal to

$$\int_{C_1+C_2}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell=-\int_{(1,1)\,\text{to}\,(0,0)}(xy^2dx+x^2ydy)=\int_0^1 2t^3=\frac12$$

---

**METHOD 2:**

If we choose to evaluate the line integral directly, that is without deforming the contour as in Method 1, then we proceed as follows.

$$\int_{C_1+C_2}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell=\int_{C_1}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell+\int_{C_2}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell$$

where

$$\int_{C_1}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell=\int_0^1 (x(0)^2)dx =0 \tag 1$$

and

$$\int_{C_2}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell=\int_0^1 (1)^2y\,dy=\frac12 \tag 2$$

Putting together $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain

$$\int_{C_1+C_2}\vec F\cdot d\vec \ell=\frac12$$

as expected!

Comment: Sorry if I can't make this comment here but I really like your answer. Can you help me with my last question? It's on my profile

Comment: @Ayesca Thank you for your comment.